# Make one field non-optional when another field in passed

Tags: typescript

I have an interface like this:

```
interface A {
    a: number;
    b?: string;
    c?: string;
}
```

and I would like to make the following code work:

```
// obj: A
// this should not throw errors
obj.b && obj.c

// this should throw errors since I want to make c mandatory when b is passed
let obj2: A = { a: 1, b: "test" }
```

I tried to do it this way:

```
type A = ({ b: string, c: string } | {}) & { a: number }
```

but then the first case throws errors and the second does not.

It there a way to make it work in TypeScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following union:

```
type A = { a: number, b?: never, c?: never } | { a: number, b: string, c: string }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeUCGAuKA7ArgWwCMIAnAGigIH5MsIA3E8gY2u3pKgF8oAfZNGviJkKmAM7BiASywBzZuMkzZXAFCqAJhCYAbVMWhMA9lglQjBAFaYYAblUB6B1GAALKWKhjXRnDo3YRsAursRGAO5QJGHEYqoWlgB0BFAAZKnmVolM6k4hHl4+fgFuYZHRRrFeMkzQAJJQ4ahYwcBGUHioANaGHc0aqG3EII2uEFgUUAVgqGJiEBqqOhDBCQBMNgj8GFAAjOQEmABEwBASR1xAA)

A bit verbose, probably can be generalized using mapped/conditional types

Comment: Thank you so much. I ended up using:

type Stub<T> = { [key in keyof T]?: never }
interface WithB { b: string, c: string }
interface BaseA { a: number }
type A = (WithB | Stub<WithB>) & BaseA

Comment: @ŁukaszKarczewski Can you explain what is going on in your answer?. Why are `b` and `c` typed `never`

Comment: @IvanV. `never` used to prevent assigning any value to these keys, so you can provide only `a` or `a`, `b` and `c` together making `{ a: 1, b: "test" }` invalid